# "The dog ate one of the boys’ breakfast."

Tags: genitive-construction

Is this correct ?

> "The dog ate one of the boys’ breakfast."

My other way to say that is:

> "The dog ate the breakfast of one of the boys."

I guess the 2nd is correct.

Comment: It's OK, but more likely is ... _one of the boys' breakfasts_, since boys and breakfasts are in one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: In the first example breakfast should be plural - - "one of the [boys'] breakfasts".  Same as when we say "one of the apples", "one of them", etc.

Comment: No, breakfast must not be pluralized in the first example. The dog ate one doggone breakfast. "one of the boys" is a single person, and the whole thing becomes a possessive the with the "z" sound at the end, by a well-defined process in English by which entire noun phrases become possessive.

Comment: Whenever one uses the expression "one of the..." the missing word has to be plural - since "one of" clearly implies there are more than one. "The dog ate one of the breakfasts" is correct. Now to indicate whose breakfast was eaten, the possessive "boys'" is introduced, with the apostrophe after the s, indicating more than one boy. However, there may only have been one boy possessed of a number of breakfasts - e.g. one for each day he was camping. In which case the sentence becomes "The dog ate one of the boy's breakfasts".

Comment: @kaz "boys' breakfast" tells there is one breakfast shared by the boys. "boys' breakfasts" tells us that each boy has a breakfast.  "One of the boys' breakfasts" is singular as it is "one of the breakfasts".  The "one of" does not belong to "boys" but to "breakfasts"

Comment: This may be a regional thing. But for me, breakfast is the meal, collectively. We ate breakfast at Dennys, I had eggs and she had waffles.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, "One of the boys" is the only way I can parse this. The dog ate one of the boys' homework, yes? This construction isn't wrong, it's a question of whether it is proper here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the following is certainly correct:

1. ... the breakfast of one of the boys.

Because the breakfast belongs to "one of they boys", we can move that phrase before "breakfast" and give it a possessive marker (in this case, an apostrophe) to indicate possession:

2. ... one of the boys' breakfast.<sup>1</sup>

This is a bit unusual because the marker does not apply to the word that it is directly attached to ("boys"); the breakfast does not belong to them. Instead, it applies to the entire phrase, whose essence is in the word "one" (representing a single boy). Because the marker is not attached to "one", this is somewhat odd, and in my opinion it is weaker than the previous version. We can try to improve it by moving the marker to "one":

3. *... one's of the boys breakfast.

However, that is ungrammatical. Instead, we can try to fix sentence #2 in another way:

4. ... one of the boys' breakfasts.

This is fine; the breakfasts belong to the boys, and the marker is attached to the word that is actually possessive. (Note that in this sentence, "one" represents a breakfast, not a boy.)

To summarize: Sentences #1 and #4 are correct and natural. Sentence #2 may be grammatically correct but is a weaker option.

Note 1: A noun normally has only one determiner, so the definite article before "breakfast" gets eliminated.

Comment: Thank you, Marc !  I got it.

Comment: @cschaka The English possessive is weird in this respect (re: #2).  People say things like "the teacher of my last class's dog ate the boy across the street's breakfast."  The possessive marker is applied to the end of the entire noun phrase.  For whatever reason it seems rather more awkward when you see it written down, so it's often better to rephrase, as you suggest in the question, especially when writing.

Comment: @phoog: Many native English speakers do not consider (2) correct. It's on the same level of wrongness as "between you and I", but perhaps not on the same level as "would of".

Comment: @user21820 I am a native English speaker, and I would say things like "the guy in the library's car" in casual speech, but not in writing.  And I would try to avoid saying it in casual speech, but sometimes it just slips out. Are there native speakers who aren't burdened with the need to resist the possessive clitic?  I would never say nor write "between you and I," so for me at least they're definitely not on the same level of wrongness. (I don't suppose it's possible to tell from my speech whether I'm saying "would've" or "would of," which is no doubt why the latter arose from the former.)

Comment: @phoog: Yes of course all native speakers sometimes want to make a possessive out of a complex noun phrase. That's why I said "many" rather than "all" do not consider (2) correct. It's interesting that you would never say/write "between you and I" since it's somewhat common and not just a recent thing. As for "would of", of course we know how it happened; some people were never taught properly how those contractions are formed, and just wrote what they spoke without first checking.

Comment: The possessive marker not applying to the word it is directly attached to is incredibly common in everyday English: *the king of England's throne".

Comment: What if you mean that the dog ate the breakfast that belonged to one of the boys but none of the other boys had any breakfast? Your fix of sentence 2 changes its meaning because it now asserts that there was more than one breakfast.

Comment: Thank you, guys.  As a native Romanian having learnt English gradually in life, also by listening to native English speakers, I diligently observe the comments of all of you and that helps me come to a conclusion.

Comment: @user21820 I've come to realize (some years out of school!) that "correct" depends on the register. For example, I would say that "there's three options" is incorrect in writing and formal speech, but I say it all the time. The same is true for #2. When I was much younger, I endeavored to speak as I was being taught to write. In later years I came to understand that there are different shades of incorrectness, as your initial comment suggests. (For learners the first important distinction is perhaps between "incorrect but understandable" and "nonsense" or "means something different.")

Comment: @Kaz also, where Alice and Bob own a house together, "Alice and Bob's house."  Of course, "Alice's and Bob's house" is also correct there, and arguably better, especially in formal use, but "Alice and Bob's house" is so common and natural that I probably wouldn't even stumble over it in a written text (whereas I probably would stumble over the possessive _'s_ applied to a noun phrase that ends with prepositional phrase).

Comment: @phoog: Indeed! Grammatical slips are common and tolerated in informal speech, as long as it is easily understood to have the intended meaning. Speech also tends to encourage ungrammatical terser constructions, whether for brevity or euphony or both. And "Alice and Bob's house" is a good one; I would indeed use the formal version but wouldn't really complain about it, since I'm not a fan of code-duplication! =)

Comment: I'm also with @Kaz in their (also) well-explained post that the meanings of the different grammatical options are different.

Comment: @phoog "Alice and Bob's house" is a good example, because in that case there might be some ambiguity: If I say "I see Alice and Bob's house," am I look at both Bob's house and Alice or the house that they share? So in addition to formal "correctness", there is an issue of clarity that may need to be considered.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, sentence #4 inidicates that there were multiple breakfasts, though that wasn't specified in the original sentence.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I agree with everything in your comment, so I don't see why you say that the footnote is incorrect. I mean that because the determiner "one of the boys'" is placed at the front of the noun phrase, the other determiner ("the") is no longer appropriate.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Ah, I misunderstood what you meant there, in that case :)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly,

> The dog ate one of the boys’ breakfast.

is perfectly gramamtical. There are some subtleties at play.

In English, complex noun phrases can take a possessive marker. This is articulated by a feature that involves the "z" sound, being tacked onto the last word of the noun phrase.

The word which takes the "z" sound is not necessarily possessor; it's just the word that happens to be at the end of the noun phrase.

For instance, consider the phrase "the queen of England's crown". The crown is of the queen, not of England!

However, also consider the phrase *the majority of England's population*. Here we have the same kinds of words in the same order, but the meaning is different. This time it is England which is the possessor.

You likely noticed that some comments are insisting that *breakfasts* should be pluralized. This is not so. It is possible, but it changes the interpretation of the sentence.

The original sentence with the singular *breakfast* parses like this:

> The dog ate ((one of the boys)' breakfast).

The noun phrase *one of the boys* refers to a single individual, and that individual had one breakfast which the dog ate instead of him. That *breakfast* should not be pluralized, if it is to support this interpretation.

The sentence with the plural *breakfasts* parses in two ways. Most likely like this:

> The dog ate (one of ((the boys)' breakfasts)).

Now the word *one* refers to a breakfast, not to a boy. Here, *the boys' breakfasts* is a  noun phrase denoting the set of breakfasts belonging to all the boys, and the dog ate one of these.

The nuance is completely different: in the first sentence, there is a focus on the idea that a particular boy was robbed of his breakfast by a dog, whereas in the second sentence, the idea conveyed is that a collective of boys were robbed of a breakfast.

(The following parse is also plausible:

> The dog ate ((one of the boys)' breakfasts).

but now requires the idea that one particular boy is individually associated with multiple breakfasts. In the context it may be that the dog was targeting the same boy on multiple mornings, and so ate more than one of that same boy's breakfasts. Or simply that the boy was served more than one breakfast.)

The semantic difference is significant because it affects how the sentence relates to its context. For instance, the first sentence could be introducing the boy as a topic, which is then discussed in the next sentence:

> The dog ate one of the boys' breakfast. That boy was upset, but befriended the dog, who eventually became his constant companion.

We cannot substitute the plural *breakfasts* here without causing a problem, because then the first sentence does not introduce the topic of a particular boy (unless we take the second parse interpretation: one boy, multiple breakfasts). Otherwise it only talks about breakfasts, which happen to belong to some boys, none of whom are singled out. Thus, the phrase *that boy* in the second sentence is left dangling without an antecedent.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem surely it's a *more* polite way of saying that :)

Comment: You are wrong, as noted by multiple commenters on the post itself.

Comment: @Black I live in Vancouver, Canada and have been exposed to a lifetime of English media from all over the world, but mostly North America. It is my observation that English speakers sometimes specially articulate a possessive that is applied into a plural word which already ends with a "z" phoneme. It might just be North American speakers.

Comment: Excellent answer. In your *the majority of England's population* example, perhaps you could clarify that it’s not just about where the possessive goes - it’s a completely different structure: *the majority of (England's population)* and not e.g. *(the majority of England)‘s population*.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. It is something used more by children than adults, I think.

Comment: @HenrikN In that example, the possessive is on the word that is being attributed, so not much explanation is required. It's when the marker is remote: "the queen of England's crown", we face the rule that it goes onto the "wrong" word at the end. We cannot move the possesive marker to "the queen's of England crown" even though the crown is the queen's.   Other kinds of markers don't do that, e.g. plural: "queen of England" goes to "queens of England" and not "queen of Enlands".

Answer (score 1):

**I am now persuaded that "one of the boys' breakfast" is grammatical (as well as the plural "one of the boys' breakfasts").**

Breakfast can be either a count or non-count noun - "James and I had breakfast together", or "We walked into the dining room and ordered two breakfasts".

Indeed the position should have been obvious from the outset, if one considers a more consistently non-count noun - e.g."food", or "water" - one would not think of pluralising it.

Indeed we would say "The dog ate one of the boys' food" or "...drank one of the boys' water".

And we would, I suspect, also say "The dog ate one of the boys' lunch". I don't think it would be "lunches". Though the implied suggestion here is of a scenario, where the meals are unitised e.g in pre-prepared style, lending more to the possibility of pluralisation - so it might be "lunches".

**However so far as idiomacy is concerned I think one would more likely see either "the dog ate one of the boys' breakfasts" or "...the breakfast of one of the boys".But "The dog ate one of the boys' breakfast" is clearly a grammatical sentence.**

Answer (score 0):

WHen in doubt,  deconstruct!

Simple rule: remove "boys'" and see how you'd write it. You would write "The dog ate one of the breakfasts." The word "boys'" merely modifies the direct object.

Use this same approach when dealing with many grammatical concerns.  A common error people (at least in the USA) write is the infamous " They gave an award to Joe and I."  If you deconstruct by removing 'Joe' it becomes obvious that "I" is wrong and "me" should be used.   Reverse that for  "Joe and me went to the store."

Comment: This looks good, but gets the structure all wrong. You can't deconstruct it this way because it's not constructed this way! The *the* in "[one [of [the boys]]]' breakfast" belongs with the noun *boys*, not with the noun *breakfast*!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.   I don't think that's a correct parsing of the entire sentence.  I see how you could interpret it that way but I wouldn't  say that the "normal" or "expected" way is to assume that  it's  {one of [adjective plural]} breakfast vs. my reading as  " one of the [adjective] breakfasts  "  .   Suppose instead you saw  " the dog ate one of the green breakfast[?s]"   It's the plural "boys" that misleads you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The word *boys'* there is not an adjective, although I can see why one might think it is. There is an alternative parse, but the *the*  still belongs with *boys* there: [one [of [[the boys'] [breakfast]]. But back to the adjective/Determiner question, consider this simple data, bearing in mind that English only allows one central Determiner per noun phrase: (1) **The** book. - (2) **Ben's** book. (3) * **The Ben's** book. <-- That last example is ungrammatical because it uses two Determiners. If *Ben's* was an adjective, there'd be no problem: (4) **The** large book.

Comment: This changes the meaning of the sentence. It's clear to me that what is meant in the question is that the dog ate a breakfast that belonged to one of the boys. If you just say "the dog ate one of the breakfasts", that could be any breakfast. So you would have to add additional context.

Comment: @CaveJohnson as I commented somewhere,  suppose the dog ate "one of the green breakfasts" . Then what?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft As mentioned in reply to that comment above  *green* is an adjective modifying *breakfasts*, but there is no adjective or other modifier of *breakfast* in the OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

There's another subtle thing here.   If you go with the approach that "one of the boys'"  is the sub-phrase, then remove it and you get "The dog ate breakfast."  Here "breakfast" is a concept, i.e., that meal eaten in the morning.  But if you write the "dog ate one of the breakfasts" (plural required), then the dog has selected from a set of physical objects available.

Back to the original sentence: I still view the fact that "boys'" is plural is a red herring.  If it were "the dog ate the one of the boy's breakfast" that would clearly be ungrammatical. Making "breakfast" plural there would work. {granted this would be a rich boy with multiple breakfasts laid out for him}

However, as Marcin_notMarceau_Manhattan suggests, readability and smoothness of flow matters.  "The dog ate one of the boys' breakfasts" is the least jarring way to go and is grammatically acceptable.